# Base relacional y Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, spring-boot

Mi tabla cliente tenía el campo email

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
@SecondaryTable(name = "distrito", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id"))
public class Cliente implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        
    //Propiedades
    
    
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    
    
    /*@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="login_cli_id")
    private LoginCliente email;
    */
    
    @Column(name="apellido")
    private String apellido;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="dni")
    private java.lang.String dni;
    
    
    @Column(name="direccion")
    private String direccion;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "distrito_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Distrito distritoId;

    @Column(name="telefono")
    private String telefono;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="tiempo_crea_cli", updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp tiempoCreaCli;
```

pero lo saque y lo movi a la tabla login

```
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @EqualsAndHashCode @Entity @Table(name="login_cli") public class LoginCliente {      @Id     @Column(name="email")   private String email;       @Column(name="dni")     private String Dni;         @Column(name="password")    private byte[] password;
```

estan unidas por el dni del cliente. Saque email para hacer mas facil el login, solo pido email y password. Ahora trato de listar Cliente pero quiero hacerlo con el email

En el ClienteRepository

```
@Query(value="Select c.dni,c.nombre, c.apellido, c.direccion, c.distrito_id, c.telefono, l.email as  email, c.tiempo_crea_cli from cliente c inner join distrito d on c.distrito_id=d.id, inner join login_cli l on c.dni=l.dni", nativeQuery = true)   public abstract List<Cliente> listadoCliente();
```

pero al no tener campo de email no hace el bind... pero si pongo el campo de email me cambia el metodo de insertar porque yo registro el cliente en dos tablas

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = { SQLException.class })     @PostMapping("/registraCliente")    public String registraCliente(Cliente obj,@RequestParam("email") String email,@RequestParam("password") String password) {      String mensaje="";      try {
                        Cliente c = service.insertaCliente(obj);            LoginClienteController hash=new LoginClienteController();           LoginCliente lc=serv.insertaLoginCliente(c.getDni(),email,hash.enfuscarPassword(password));             if(lc!=null) {
                mensaje="cliente registrado";           }       }catch(Exception e) {           mensaje = e.toString();
                    }finally {          logger.info("Mensaje: "+mensaje);
                    }       return "intranet_registra_cliente";     }
```

Soy programador junior y no sé como sería mejor diseñar mis tablas y unirlas.  Quiero obtener el email de la tabla login_cli para el Listado de Cliente. la tabla login_cli la pk es el dni. Sería mejor poner una pk auto increment en tabla login cli y eso unirla a cliente

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ``.`cliente` (
`nombre` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`apellido` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`dni` CHAR(8) primary key NOT NULL,
`telefono` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
`direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`tiempo_crea_cli` TIMESTAMP,
`distrito_id` int NOT NULL,

le añado un *login_cli_id int not null* como fk a cliente
y

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ``.`login_cli` (
    *id int auto_increment primary key not null,*
    `dni` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(30) not null,
    `password` varbinary(256) not null)
```

como debo diseñar mis tablas?